# Create link from custom autosuggest autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following autosuggest/autocomplete which returns a dynamic list when a user types in a search box:

```
if($arg) {  
    if (!$query) {  
        $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE (name LIKE \"%" . $_GET["q"] . "%\") group by name LIMIT 8";     
    }   
}

$result = mysql_query($query);

$output_items = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $output_items[] = $row[name]; 
} 

print(implode("\n", $output_items));

mysql_close();
```

When a user clicks on a name I want it link and go to e.g.

```
mysite.com/search.html?firstname+lastname
```

I have seen answers on the jquery version but I think this is probably simpler but it has stumped me.

Answer (score 0):

1. for html form input text (search) hook event keyup
2. in jQuery:

   ```
   this.keyup(function() { 
       $.getJSON('mysite.com/search.html?name='+name,function(data) { 
           info = data.users;
           $('#suggest-result').html('');   
           for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
               jQuery('<a/>', {
                   href: '#',
                   title: info[i].user_name,
                   text: info[i].user_name
               }).appendTo('#suggest-result');  
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. In html template create div '#suggest-result' for output users

Comment: thanks for this but I'm a little new to jquery and js to be honest, how is this implemented exactly? Like where on the page etc.

Comment: Please write me inbox <kal1sha.ua@gmail.com> or skype <kal1sha>